# How To Fix: 'Variables in different modules not working'

Tags: python

Code gets the players name in the entryQuestions section. When it gets to 'loadCasino', the code shows an error.

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "main.py", line 38, in 
>           loadCasino()
>       File "main.py", line 34, in loadCasino
>           print("Arrived at Casino. Standby", name)
>   NameError: name 'name' is not defined"

My code contains 'replit.clear()' functions. Would this clear variables too, if so, maybe that's the issue.

```
def entryQuestions():
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Please answer the following questions to log into the 
  Casino.")
  time.sleep(1)
  name = input("Please enter a Username: ")
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Information loaded.")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("Beginning transportation to Casino...")

def loadCasino():
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Transporting to Casino.")
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Transporting to Casino..")
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Transporting to Casino...")
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Arrived at Casino. Standby", name)
```

Expected results should be the script printing "Arrived at Casino. Standby, (name here)".

The code is being used on repl.it and can be found [here](https://repl.it/@harrisoncopp/Frenzy-Casino?language=python3):

```
import replit
import time

replit.clear()

def topBanner():
  replit.clear()
  print("======================================")
  print("Frenzy Casino - Made by @harrisoncopp")
  print("======================================")

def entryQuestions():
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Please fill in the details below to create, or login to, a new accont in order to play at the Casino.")

# REGISTER / LOGIN WILL GO HERE

def loadCasino():
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Transporting to Casino.")
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Transporting to Casino..")
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Transporting to Casino...")
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Arrived at Casino. Standby")

topBanner()
entryQuestions()
loadCasino()
```

Comment: replit.clear() clears the screen

Comment: Name is not defined because you haven't assigned it anywhere in the scope

Comment: You might consider to update your code such that it becomes a running script that replicates the error as mentioned. Now its just a bunch of `defs` only. You need to include `import replit` and preferably a version number (if not provided by the replit tag). Please read how to post questions and its conditions. Send from triage question > Requires editing.

Answer (score 2):

You needed to assign `name` in the local scope of `loadcasino()`.

I simply returned the name variable from entry quesitions. And passed it to the `loadcasion()` function.

```
import replit
import time

replit.clear()

def topBanner():
  replit.clear()
  print("======================================")
  print("Frenzy Casino - Made by @harrisoncopp")
  print("======================================")

def entryQuestions():
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Please answer the following questions to log into the Casino.")
  time.sleep(1)
  name = input("Please enter a Username: ")
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Information loaded.")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("Beginning transportation to Casino...")
  return name

def loadCasino():
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Transporting to Casino.")
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Transporting to Casino..")
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Transporting to Casino...")
  time.sleep(2)
  replit.clear()
  print("Arrived at Casino. Standby", name)

topBanner()
name = entryQuestions()
loadCasino(name)
```

I checked your repl.it code and the `name` variable had been underlined red. It told you it hadn't been defined. You should try and follow the editor's auto-checking.

Comment: It is defined, just in a separate definition I thought.